# How to create chart image on nodejs server

Tags: node.js, charts

How can i create a line chart on the nodejs server, and return an image to client?

i see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477008/how-to-create-charts-using-nodejs) and not work for me.

Comment: you might also want to delegate the rendering to something else like https://image-charts.com or https://developers.google.com/chart/image/ :)

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple approaches.  If it were me, I'd just create a rest JSON service that returned the raw data, then render it with jqplot on the client side.

Edit - If you need to create a PNG, then I might use:  npmjs.com/package/nchart

Comment: the client side in web and applications, i need to create it on nodejs server.

Comment: Ah, you need to use something like nchart then, to create a png.  For example: https://www.npmjs.com/package/nchart