# How to use Chart.js in Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, canvas, chart.js

How to create a pie chart using NodeJs with `chartjs`?
want to create different types of charts using `chartjs` but when I tried to run the code shows "cannot set the property of width"

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'width' of undefined
    at ni.resize (node_modules\chart.js\dist\Chart.min.js:7:93312)
    at ni.initialize (node_modules\chart.js\dist\Chart.min.js:7:92818)
    at ni.construct (node_modules\chart.js\dist\Chart.min.js:7:92559)
    at new ni (node_modules\chart.js\dist\Chart.min.js:7:91964)
    at Object.<anonymous> (chartjs\chart.js:7:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
```

I tried to run this code to produce a pie chart image but found this error.

```
let Canvas = require("canvas"),
  canvas = Canvas.createCanvas(400, 400),
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
  Chart = require('chart.js'),
  fs = require("fs");

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: "pie",
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "# of Votes",
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        backgroundColor: [
          "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)",
          "rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)",
          "rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)",
          "rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)",
          "rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)",
          "rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)"
        ],
        borderColor: [
          "rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)",
          "rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)",
          "rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)",
          "rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)",
          "rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)",
          "rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)"
        ],
        borderWidth: 1
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [
        {
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
});

canvas.toBuffer(function(err, buf) {
  if (err) throw err;
  fs.writeFileSync("chart.png", buf);
});
```

Should be an image in the current folder

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create charts using NodeJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477008/how-to-create-charts-using-nodejs)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using ChartJS for Node: https://www.npmjs.com/package/chartjs-node

It draws a chart which you can then save to the file system and insert accordingly.

Here's a snippet of code as an example:

```
import * as ChartjsNode from 'chartjs-node'; // Import the library

const chartNode = new ChartjsNode(600, 600); // Create an instance with dimensions

const barGraphOptions = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: []
};

// Draw the chart and write the file to the file system
await new Promise(resolve => {
  chartNode
    .drawChart(barGraphOptions)
    .then(() => {
      chartNode.getImageBuffer('image/png');
    })
    .then(() => {
      chartNode.writeImageToFile('image/png', 'some_file.png').then(() => {
        resolve();
      });
    })
    .catch(e => {
      console.log('Caught', e);
    });
});
```

Comment: [What is the explicit promise construction antipattern and how do I avoid it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it). Also, this is confusing because there's nothing returned by the `then` blocks, so they aren't awaiting anything.

Answer (score 1):

`ChartJS` is an HTML5 based file which is used in front-end development only.
For more information visit [this](https://www.chartjs.org/) site.

You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15479920/7514132) answer if you want to use `nodejs` to create Charts.

P.S. This question is duplicate to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477008/how-to-create-charts-using-nodejs)

Comment: It's not really a duplicate--the other question asks how to draw charts in Node, while this one asks how to use chart.js specifically.

Comment: @ggorlen The answer is already in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71750361/7514132). The question is not exactly the same but, the implementation is same.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as OP. I couldn't figure out a way to do it using the standard approach of combining Node Canvas and Chart.JS, but I found using [ChartjsNodeCanvas](https://github.com/SeanSobey/ChartjsNodeCanvas) works.

```
import { CanvasRenderService } from 'chartjs-node-canvas';

canvasRenderService: CanvasRenderService;

async createGraph(data: any) {

    const configuration = {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: // Your labels,
            datasets: [
                data
            ]
        },
        options: {
           // Your options
        }
    };

    const canvasRenderService = new CanvasRenderService(300, 500);

    return await canvasRenderService.renderToDataURL(configuration);
    // or return canvasRenderService.renderToBuffer(configuration);
    // or return canvasRenderService.renderToStream(configuration);
}


await this.createGraph(data);
```

Note, ChartjsNodeCanvas requires ChartJS as a dependency.